# javascript function to uncheck input checkbox before sending

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have difficulty to solve this and would ask your help !
I'm trying to make a javascript but i had no success
i have inside a form below, two input checkbox, when the user press the submit
i want to verify if the two checkbox is checked, if they are checked i want to
disable the two before sending it to another page, 
and if only one of then is checked, i want to do nothing.

```
<form action="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/search/">
<input type="checkbox" checked = "checked"  name="new[equal]" value="1" /> New <br>
<input type="checkbox" checked = "checked"  name="used[equal]" value="1" /> Used <br>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="[[Find:raw]]" />
</form>
```

thank you friends

Comment: I am not sure I understand why you want to disable the check boxes when on that condition you will be displaying a new page? Perhaps just testing that both are checked and returning false from the Submit is preferable?

Comment: because the system already does select of new and used cars by default, the script is ready made, I'm not 100% familiar with the system, and I have to open it tomorrow, so I asked for this quick fix.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
var new = document.forms[0]["new[equal]"],
    used = document.forms[0]["used[equal]"]
    if(new.checked && used.checked){
        new.disabled = true;
        used.disabled = true;
    }
```

If you have multiple forms on the page then you should provide a `name` to the `form` and use the form name to select the required form.

Something like this will do.

`document.formName.elementName` or `document.formName['elementName']`

**Update:**
If you want to validate this on submit button click then you can create a JS function with above code and call it on submit button click

HTML

```
<input type="submit" onclick="ValidateForm()" value="Submit" />
```

JS

```
function ValidateForm(){
   var new = document.forms[0]["new[equal]"],
        used = document.forms[0]["used[equal]"]
        if(new.checked && used.checked){
            new.disabled = true;
            used.disabled = true;
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering ShankarSangoli, but how can I put that in the onclick event, on submit input ???

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here : http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

It explains to you how you can use jquery to check if a checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: OP is asking for JavaScript solution and its not a good idea to load complete Jquery library for such a small task.